# LIKE inside CASE

Tags: sql

Hello can anyone help me with this code?
Iam trying to select employee IDs from employees table TabCisZam. Every employee has an alias which is either ERP, ESh or TO or a combination of these - `'ERP, TO'` or `'ESh,TO'` depending to which department they belong (TO - technicians, ERP - Enterprice Resource Planning, ESh - EShop)

```
DECLARE @DruhPozadavku NVARCHAR(3) = 'OST'
SELECT ID FROM TabCisZam where Alias LIKE 
    CASE WHEN @DruhPozadavku IN ('Heo','Set') THEN '%ERP%' 
    WHEN @DruhPozadavku IN ('SW','Inf') THEN '%TO%' 
    WHEN @DruhPozadavku = 'OST' THEN '%TO%'+'%ERP%'
END
)
```

When the @DruhPozadavku is equal to 'Ost' I want to get all the users with the string `ERP` or `TO` in their aliases. So far it does not return any value.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? I suppose that the `+` in `'%TO%'+'%ERP%'` is a non-standard string concatenation operator in your DBMS? Is this SQL Server maybe? Please tag your request with your DBMS.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: This is a bad data model. Don't store relations in comma-separated strings, store them in a separate table. As is, your database table is not normalized, it violates first normal form, and this is a reason why you have difficulties selecting your data. Fix the database design.

Comment: `LIKE` is followed by a pattern for the strings you are looking for. You have `WHERE alias LIKE '%TO%%ERP%`. There is no string matching this pattern in your table. You cannot just concatenate LIKE patterns to say "match one or the other", a string will always have to match the complete pattern.

Answer (score 1):

In WHERE clauses you can always use simple boolean logic instead of CASE

```
SELECT ID 
FROM TabCisZam 
WHERE (@DruhPozadavku IN ('Heo','Set') AND Alias LIKE '%ERP%')
   OR (@DruhPozadavku IN ('SW','Inf') AND Alias LIKE '%TO%')
   OR (@DruhPozadavku = 'OST' AND (Alias LIKE '%TO%' OR Alias LIKE '%ERP%'))
```

Comment: It seems they really want `OR (@DruhPozadavku = 'OST' AND (Alias LIKE '%TO%' OR Alias LIKE '%ERP%'))`. Quote: "When the @DruhPozadavku is equal to 'Ost' I want to get all the users with the string ERP or TO in their alias".